# How do I make the navigation title a different size in one view controller?

Tags: objective-c

I have a view controller that segues into another.  The project contains code to set the navigation title to 36pt font.  However, I want to have the title shrink to 20pt font when the second view controller is opened.  Inserting the code to set the title to 26 point font inside the .m file for the second view controller does not appear to work.  How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use titleTextAttributes property on navigation bar to change font, background, foreground colours and even more.
Add this code to viewDidLoad method:

```
NSDictionary *attributesDict = @{NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont systemFontOfSize:26], NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor redColor]};

self.navigationController.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = attributesDict;
[self setTitle:@"TEST"];
```